# Sscanf reads a line twice?

Tags: c, io, text-files, scanf, csv

All I want to do is read numbers from a text file, do something with them, and move on.

The text file is formatted like:

```
0,0,16
0,3,17
0,4,10
...etc.
```

Here is my code to just print the text file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
FILE *fp;    

main()
{
        char line[10];
        int row,column,data;
        fp = fopen("data.txt","rt");
        while(fgets(line, 10, fp) != NULL)
        {
            sscanf(line,"%d,%d,%d\n",&row,&column,&data);
            printf("[Row: %d Column: %d Data %d]\n", row, column, data);
        }
        fclose (fp);
}
```

Whenever I run this, it outputs each line twice so it says

```
[Row: 0 Column: 0 Data 16]
[Row: 0 Column: 0 Data 16]
...
```

instead of

```
[Row: 0 Column: 0 Data 16]
...
```

I'm very confused as to why it is doing this...

Comment: I really don't understand what I am supposed to do to fix this code

Comment: @user2154420: I don't see any problem with this code given your `data.txt` as you have specified. Is there any blank lines after every record?

Comment: Check the length of 'line' before you process it with sscanf, and make sure it's longer than the minimum you expect.  You should also check the return value from the scan.

Comment: Aha! Even though my text editor displayed it as one line after another, there was an extra newline character in between the lines so I had to backspace every line. Also, I don't understand how this is a duplicate question... this seems pretty different and the answer to the other question did not help me at all

Comment: @Ian Checking the line length has the case where the last line read may/may not end with a `'\n`` to cope with.

Comment: @chux I agree - I meant that only as a test to aid debugging

Comment: since fgets() stops at the indicated max length, or it sees/consumes a '\n' (but might not put the '\n' into the input buffer), in either case fgets() places a terminating '\0' in the next unused position in the char array.  part of the problem is the sscanf() format string is expecting the string to be terminated with '\n' which it 'may' not be for the last line in the file and can not be depended upon if reading from a file rather than from stdin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have any blank lines after every record in your `data.txt` then check if `line[0]` is `'\n'`?

Check if this code works for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
FILE *fp;    

int main()
{
        char line[10];
        int row,column,data;
        fp = fopen("data.txt","rt");
        while(fgets(line, 10, fp) != NULL)
        {
            if(line[0] == '\n')
                continue;
            sscanf(line,"%d,%d,%d\n",&row,&column,&data);
            printf("[Row: %d Column: %d Data %d]\n", row, column, data);
        }
        fclose (fp);
        return 0;
}
```

**Input file `data.txt`**:

```
0,0,16

0,3,17

0,4,10
1,2,3
```

**Output**:

```
[Row: 0 Column: 0 Data 16]
[Row: 0 Column: 3 Data 17]
[Row: 0 Column: 4 Data 10]
[Row: 1 Column: 2 Data 3]
```

Comment: Yup! This is what happened!

Comment: This assumes there are no other characters hidden on the line, like spaces etc.  Better to check the return of sscanf() too.

Comment: @Ian: I completely agree with you. As you mentioned in comment OP can also check the string length of `line`.

Answer (score 0):

After accept answer

The crux of the issues of having unexpected blank lines is only 1 potential problem of reading file input.  Rather than solve the problems one-by-one, use more robust error handling.

Well paced use of `"%n"` in the format records the offset of the scan and provides additional info to assess the correctness of the line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;    
    char line[10];
    int row,column,data;
    fp = fopen("data.txt","rt");
    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fp) != NULL)
    {
        int n1, n2;
        int cnt = sscanf(line," %n%d ,%d ,%d %n", 
            &n1, &row, &column, &data, &n2);
        if (n1 > 0 && line[n1] == '\0') 
          Handle_Line_Is_Entirely_Whitespace();
        else if (cnt != 3 || line[n2]) 
          Handle_IncorrectlyFormattedLine();
        else 
          printf("[Row: %d Column: %d Data %d]\n", row, column, data);
    }
    fclose (fp);
    return 0;  
}
```

An even more robust method would use `strtol()` to scan the `int`s.